# Why Allah is self introducing in Quran by using the word "we" instead of using "I"?

Tags: quran, allah, quran-translation, surat-yasin

Why Allah is introducing him self by using the word we instead of using I?

Here I'm adding two Ayaths from surath yaseen

8. Verily! We have put on their necks iron collars reaching to chins, so that their heads are forced up.
9. And We have put a barrier before them, and a barrier behind them, and We have covered them up, so that they cannot see.

Comment: They may possibly be using the royal "we", aka majestic plural.

Comment: I'm sure this question has been asked before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Salaam

In response to this question, please note to following points:

**1**- using plural and singular personal pronoun (we/I) for acts of Allah, is two different ways of assigning actions to Allah. Cases in which plural form has been used, indicate the role and functionalities of Allah's means such as malaikah in fulfilling actions, though in cases with singular form, not necessarily meant to deny their role, but it can be either immediate action of Allah or action that originates from Allah's will and is accomplished through his devices. Therefore, these ayahs implies that we have two types of assignments (attributions) to Allah: direct and indirect.

**2**- In this world, everything is based on the law of causality, and every phenomenon and every creature has a cause. Allah gives sustenance and this is done through causes. Allah is healer but this healing is done through causes. some part of these causes are natural and material and others are non-material. It is also the same in case of heaven and hell; Allah wants to reward or punish, they've done through malaikah. And also, Allah wants to intercede, does this through his intercessors (The holy prophet and his households). Thus intervening malaikah in rewarding or punishment, is similar to any other cause in the universe and this is obviously one of Allah's traditions.

**3**- Sometimes great people, when talking about themselves, are using plural pronouns, in order to show their power and greatness to their audiences, and to inform audiences that speaker and his speech are of great importance. For instance, in the event of creation and caliphate of Adam, Allah says: "we said"; because this happening is one of the most important issues in creation. So using all means of messaging is necessary to attract listener' mind to the sensitivity of the subject. Using plural pronouns is one of these means.

For further reading about the topic, please refer to following resources:

a. Ontology, [Imam Khomeini Institute of Educational Research](http://www.iki.ac.ir/en/).

b. Monotheistic world-view, martyr Motahhari, discussion of the longitudinal and transversal system of the universe.

c. Allah justice, Martyr Motahhari.

4- Theology of the Quran, Allameh Misbah Yazdi, Discussing the Generalities of Allah actions.

5- [Philosophical instructions, Allameh Misbah Yazdi, Discussing the causality principle](https://cdn.mashreghnews.ir/old/files/fa/news/1393/11/7/879895_624.pdf)

Comment: I red your answer, it looks helpful and true, particularly this part was interesting for me that you mentioned:  ...indicate the role and functionalities of Allah's means such as malaikah in fulfilling actions... Well done.

Answer (score 1):

Every prophet comes with Miracles (Jesus)( عيسى بن مريم) miracles  are a lot one of them he spoke when he was infant

```
قَالَ إِنِّي عَبْدُ اللَّهِ آتَانِيَ الْكِتَابَ وَجَعَلَنِي نَبِيًّا - 19:30
```

> [Jesus] said, "Indeed, I am the servant of Allah . He has given me the
>   Scripture and made me a prophet. and there are several Miracles Allah give him you cane

read about it [here](https://www.islamreligion.com/articles/352/miracles-of-jesus/)

َQuran was one of Miracles Allah give it to our prophet because The Miracles it challenge it people in what they are specialized Arab are fluent in a language so Quran comes to challenge them to bring similar one.

> وَإِن كُنتُمْ فِي رَيْبٍ مِّمَّا نَزَّلْنَا عَلَىٰ عَبْدِنَا فَأْتُوا
>   بِسُورَةٍ مِّن مِّثْلِهِ وَادْعُوا شُهَدَاءَكُم مِّن دُونِ اللَّهِ إِن
>   كُنتُمْ صَادِقِينَ - 2:23
>
> And if you are in doubt about what We have sent down upon Our Servant
>   [Muhammad], then produce a surah the like thereof and call upon your
>   witnesses other than Allah, if you should be truthful.

**`now we come to the language in Arabic`**

Such usage in Arabic refers to the one who is great and has helpers who obey him; when his helpers do something by his command, he says ‘We did it,’ as a king might say, ‘We conquered this land and we defeated this army,’ and so on.

```
 وَلِلَّهِ الْمَثَلُ الْأَعْلَىٰ ۚ وَهُوَ الْعَزِيزُ الْحَكِيمُ
```

> And the loftiest description belongs to Allah, and He is the
>   All-mighty, the All-wise.

[read here](https://islamqa.info/en/2090)